# If each of the functions $f_n$ is integrable- True/false?

Tags: real-analysis

Is  the following  statementt is  True/false ??

Let $ \{f_n\}$ be a sequence of continuous real valued functions defined on $\mathbb{R}$ converging uniformly on $\mathbb{R}$ to a function $f$.

If each of the functions $f_n$ is integrable, then
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_\infty^{-\infty} f_n(t)\,dt=\int_\infty^{-\infty } f(t) \, dt$$

## MY attempt :

It will  True  by  Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem and another  approach is that i  thinks it  will also be  True because   if i take  $f_n(t) = \frac{|sint|} {n}$  it will  satisfied this  statement

Comment: Maybe irrelevant, but should you specify that the integral is in Riemann or Lebesgue sense? For improper integrals, these two do not contain each other.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not true. Try a very short but even longer triangle sitting on the $x$ axis. Bad picture:

$$ \_\Delta\_$$
eg $1/n$ height and $n^{2}$ width. The convergence to 0 is uniform but the integrals get larger.

Explicit formula: define $T(x)=\max(0,1-|x|)$. Then set $$f_n(x)=\frac{1}{n} T\left(\frac x{n^{2}}\right)$$

I suggest you draw these, but use your highschool formula for the area of a triangle instead of trying to compute the integral.

Comment: Classic example. +1

Comment: im not getting  can  u   elaborate more..

Comment: @stupid I've given the explicit formula of the graph if it wasn't clear from the word description

Comment: @CalvinKhor..thank u   i got its

Comment: @stupid You could know that $\sup_{\mathbb R}(f_n(x)) = 1/n \to 0$, hence the uniform convergence to $0$, and the integral is $n/2$, but clearly the integral diverges, while the limit function is $0$ hence its integral is $0$.

Comment: @ xbh  yaaa...i misses  that  point..thank u for clarify